# Socle and Radical Series

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ a $R$-module. The we define $\text{rad}^n(M) := \text{rad}(\text{rad}^{n-1}(M))$ and $\text{soc}^n(M)$ as the preimage in $M$ of the socle of $M/\text{soc}^{n-1}(M)$. Now I have no idea how to prove the following two statements:

(i) $\text{soc}^n(M) = M$ iff $\text{rad}^n(M) = 0$,

(ii) for a morhpism of modules $f: M \rightarrow N$ we have $f(\text{soc}^n(M)) \subset \text{soc}^n(N)$.

My biggest problem is the power n, I think you cannot show the equality straightforward. What's the trick here?

A hint or two would be great! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint for (i). Suppose $M=\mathrm{soc}^n(M)$. Why is the composite $\mathrm{rad}(M)\to M\to M/\mathrm{soc}^{n-1}(M)$ zero?

Comment: Hint for (ii). By induction we have an induced map $M/\mathrm{soc}^{n-1}(M)\to N/\mathrm{soc}^{n-1}(N)$.

Comment: Addendum for (i). The implication $\mathrm{rad}(M)=0$ implies $M$ semisimple does not hold in general. It holds if $R/J(R)$ is semisimple, or if $M$ is finitely generated.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps a lot!

Comment: @AndrewHubery Can you give a hint how your hint for (i) helps? How can I relate the composite map $\operatorname{rad}(M) \rightarrow M \rightarrow M / \operatorname{soc} ^{n-1} (M)$ to $\operatorname{rad} ^n(M)$?

Comment: The hint implies that $\mathrm{rad}(M)$ lies in $\mathrm{soc}^{n-1}(M)$. Now use induction on $n$.